# specifying many Outlook inspectors in RibbonType does not work: custom tab does not show on Explorer, Mail.Read

Tags: c#, email, outlook, ms-office, vsto

I would like to display a custom tab on ribbons of three types of Outlook windows:

1. main window (Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer)
2. new message window (Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose), and
3. read existing mail window (Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read)

I am specifying (in that order) comma-separated list of namespaces in the RibbonType property, as:

```
this.RibbonType = "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read";
```

However, the custom tab ONLY appears in the new mail window (Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose), and **does not** appear in the other two window types.

I cannot figure out why. Anyone solved this before?

How can I debug, diagnose the issue? This is all Office+VSTO internals, I don't have anywhere to put a breakpoint.

Comment: When is that code called? Why can't you set a breakpoint on that line? Also try to get rid of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a new sample Outlook add-in and set the [RibbonType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.ribbontype#Microsoft_Office_Tools_Ribbon_RibbonBase_RibbonType) property as shown above. Viola! I can see a custom markup in all cases.

Most probably you get an UI error. Make sure that the *Show add-in user interface errors* checkbox is selected in the Outlook settings. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-show-add-in-user-interface-errors) for more information.

Comment: I also enabled logging to ".../AppData/Local/Temp", per directions here: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/What-is-the-Enable-logging-troubleshooting-option-0fdc446d-d1d4-42c7-bd73-74ffd4034af5 but that does not have file where any UI errors would be reported. I confirm I see this functionality working in a "blank sample" solution but I cannot make it work in the real one - all properties between sample and real solutions for OfficeRibbon and RibbonTab are identical. If the problem is a UI composition error - I get no logs or reports about it. How else could I track down the root cause?

Comment: I had that option enabled for a while - I never saw any indication of existence of errors in UI. Have you seen any UI errors reported due to this option? Is it done via MessageBox or a log statement (where)?

Comment: Yes, a message box is displayed if the ribbon xml markup contains an error. It looks like the issue depends on the Ribbon content you added to the tab.